# Why do you need to await app.listen() for nestjs

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, nestjs

Sorry if it's a stupid question I don't see why in nest you need to await app.listen(), what is the point when it's the last thing bootstrap() is doing anyways

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

Comment: Because it does some asynchronous stuff. if your question is , *What asynchronous about it?* Then you should ask that to the collaborators of  `nestjs`, They would give you more accurate information about it...

Comment: @Nur yes but isn't await still redundant? it's the same as putting app.listen(3000).then(e => {}); literally telling it to do nothing after the promise has resolved, are u sure it isn't just a "best practice" sorta thing?

Comment: Why would that be ? There is reason, like reading from disk,  Need to do when startup...

Comment: @Nur because regardless of await the promise will start right? like all await is doing here is saying "do nothing after the promise has been resolved"

Comment: Does `app.listen` even return a promise? If yes, when does it resolve? In this example it's not needed because you are not `await`ing `bootstrap` either. But  if `app.listen` returns a promise that e.g. resolves when the app *stops* to listen, then it might be useful (e.g. to do something after teardown).

Comment: But I believe there are also lint rules around calling an async function without `await`ing the return value. That would be another reason for using `await`.

Comment: @FelixKling it returns a reference to the underlying HttpServer, you could be right it might just be a linting thing. If it were what you described (returning when it stopped to listen) I would imagine it would be in the form of a async iterator (for await (const req of server) as opposed to a single function call

Comment: *"it returns a reference to the underlying HttpServer"* You mean https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_server ? In that case using `await` is simply a mistake.

Comment: @FelixKing by returns I mean, the promise that app.listen returns resolves to the reference

Comment: It's just good practice and what nest-cli generates. If someone were to add another line after it that relies on the app being initialised, you get a subtle bug because two things have no clear order. So just keep it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you run an application through a terminal with this command:

```
 yourApp start
```

Imagine this command will start a node server locally. In the commandline part of the code, your code must have something like this

```
try{
// this has to be async
start the server here
}
catch(e){
  console.log(e.message)
  process.exit(1);
}
```

Now, if `app.listen` is a sync function, when `try` blocks run, `app.listen` won't throw any error at that moment so we will never catch that error. Even the port is in use, we would not get the "EADDRINUSE" message.

But if `app.listen` was an async code, we would catch the error and show it to the user at the terminal. Otherwise, there would be something wrong with the application after the command runs and the user would not know what happened and would never use the same app again.